# Remove unnecessary shading in Box Shadow

Tags: css

I want to Create Box shadow as given below.

As per my study of Box shadow. It takes below parameters:

```
DIV {
box-shadow: <horizontal> <vertical> <blur> <color> [inset]
}
```

Please, Find the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/hBMQm/) for this.

[image: I want to Create Box shadow as given below.]

To create above examples, I need to use box shadow.

For example 1, I used below style:

```
 box-shadow:0px 10px 22px 0px gray;
```

Here, I am getting lighter shadow on top, left and right side also (which I don't want)

In example 2, I used below style:

```
 box-shadow:10px 10px 22px 0px gray inset;
```

I don't want inner shading to right and bottom part.

Is it possible to remove unnecessary shading in box-shadow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a box shadow just on one side, on two sides, three sides, but in that case you should set the blur value to zero - see demo http://dabblet.com/gist/1579740

However, you can emulate the first kind of shadow by wrapping your div into another outer div of the same width, but slightly bigger height on which you set `overflow: hidden;`

If you don't need the background of your div to be semitransparent, then you could also emulate the second one using an absolutely positioned pseudo-element in order to obscure the bottom and right shadows.

DEMO http://dabblet.com/gist/3149980

HTML for first shadow:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="shadow1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS for first shadow

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.outer {
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shadow1 {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px 0px gray;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

---

HTML for second shadow

```
<div class="shadow2"></div>
```

CSS for second shadow

```
.shadow2 {
    box-shadow:10px 10px 22px 0px gray inset;
    position: relative;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
.shadow2:before {
    top: 22px;
    bottom:0;
    left:22px;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    content:'';
}
```

Comment: Its good Idea to wrap the div and hide the shadow than shrinking like Kyle is suggesting !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some extra markup (an extra div wrapping the element so that it hides the other shadows you don't want)

Or you could use the shadow spread property (the 4th number in the `box-shadow` declaration) to shrink the shadow down to hide the side parts of your shadow.

This creates a smaller shadow on the bottom, but it requires no extra HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/hBMQm/2/

Comment: +1. First idea of using extra markup to hide the unnecessary is better than demo example.

Answer (score 1):

```
#b {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top:200px;
    left:200px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:20px 20px 22px 0px gray inset;
 }
```

Now you have the inner shadow, but not on you right, or bottom as you asked for. Did i misunderstand you?

Answer (score 1):

box-shadow takes one more parameter the `spread`

using following code i was able to achieve the desired effect

```
box-shadow: 0px 20px 22px -20px gray inset;
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/hBMQm/3/